# Laravel Mail function is working when i do DD without DD not working

Tags: php, email, laravel-5, smtp

Here is My Mail Send code, Code is working Fine When I do DD on Mail function but without DD mail function is not working

```
dd(Mail::to($user->email)->cc('mail@gmail.com')->send(new ResetPassword($user)));
```

Comment: What are you basing it working on not working on? Afaik dd just dumps and exits, it doesn't alter what the `Mail` call is doing.

Comment: When I do dump I receive email in inbox also I got Response in php artisan queue:listen , but if i Just run the function without dump i didn't receive any email even i have waited for 30mins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below step to setup mail in laravel.
Modify the .env following parameters

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=your-gmail-username
MAIL_PASSWORD=your-application-specific-password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Use Mail Facades where you want to integrate mail feature.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
```

Send email like this.

```
Mail::raw('Text to e-mail', function($message)
    {
        $message->from('rk@example.com', 'Laravel');
        $message->subject('Mail Subject');
        $message->to('abc@example.com')->cc('bar@example.com');
    });
```

Comment: your answer is appreciated , issue is something else , Markdown is not working if i sent mail without markdown is working, when i use mark down and call like this as i did above its not working getting no errors.